# How can i use a Count distinct values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct, distinct-values

How can I do in SQL a:

```
select count(distinct(field))
from table
```

and the final result don not count empty values?

example:

[image]

the final result should be 3 but it shows 4 (due to empty value).

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Comment: What do you mean by Empty? `NULL` is excluded when using Aggregate functions.

Comment: `distinct` is not a function! Do `select count(distinct column)` instead, to make code clearer. Also, a table has _columns_, not _fields_.

Answer (score 2):

Empty clearly does not mean `NULL`, because that is not counted.  Let me assume it means an empty string, `''`.  If so:

```
select count(distinct nullif(field, ''))
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . This is a SQL standard and Oracle supports this (possibly they invented it):  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fa6f3a53bae965f716cc00e6f2097783.  In the case of Oracle, the `nullif()` is redundant, because Oracle treats `''` as `NULL` (is that what you are referring to?)

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @Gordon Linoff was the solution!!